# Service invoked too many times in a day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-translate

I am using paid google suite. Have created a google sheet and a script to be used with that sheet that uses Language.translate.
I am trying to run the script but it says

> "Service invoked too many times for one day: translate".

How can I solve this problem. Paying for the service is no problem. Just need clean instructions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to batch translate a large data in google sheets

Comment: the code is a bit too long to paste here. The sheet has 12 rows with 4 columns. Every cell is being iterated and language.translate is being called.

Comment: Trying to iterate and translate to 22 languages. It worked fine several times but then stopped and started to display the above mentioned exception. Is there a way to raise daily quota by paying?

Comment: This question looks to be asking for instructions that Google should provide on the Google Translate API documentation. Bear in mind that asking for external resources is off topic on this site.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this myself, but I believe you have to open the Google Cloud Platform project associated with your script (Resources > Cloud Platform project), enable the Translate API there and setup a billing account for this project.

I'm not sure if the Apps Script built-in Translate API interface, `LanguageApp` will work out of the box with this setup or if you'll have to switch to manual `UrlFetch` invocation of the API. My guess is that the built-in will work, but it isn't hard to switch either.

Anyways, your calls to Translate API should then be enabled and cost [$20 per 1 million characters](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing) translated.